# Karate API, How do I match 2 different responses

Tags: karate

I get 2 different responses from an endpoint depending on it's state and either one of them is fine.

first response:

```
{"available":'#boolean',"collection":'#boolean'}
```

second response:

```
{"code": "#string","message": "#string"}
```

I'm trying the following but it's not working:

- `def firstSchema = {"available":'#boolean',"collection":'#boolean'}`
- `def secondSchema = {"code": "#string","message": "#string"}`

match response contains any `(firstSchema, secondSchema)`

Any ideas how to best get this working so either response is fine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
* def first = { available: true, collection: true }
* def second = { code: 'foo', message: 'bar' }

* def response = second
* def expected = response.code ? { code: '#string', 'message': '#string' } : { available: '#boolean', collection: '#boolean' }
* match response == expected
```

Also refer to the documentation on "Conditional Logic". You can use JsonPath to "check" what shape the response is and then define expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I get 2 different responses from an endpoint and either one of them is fine.

first response:

response1.xml

second response:

response2.xml

I tried below assertion but it's not working:

And match response == read('response1.xml') || response == read('response2.xml')

Comment: Please post only answers in the answer section. You can ask a question by posting a new question. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30844884)